# How to make C program block until FIFO pipe is empty?

Tags: c, pipe, block, fifo

I'm doing IPC using named (FIFO) pipes and I would like to coordinate that program can only write into the pipe when program reading the pipe has read the previously written data out from the pipe. So I would like to block the write until the the pipe is empty. Is this possible?

One option that I though is that write function blocks when the pipe is full. But I would like to do this to much smaller amounts of data than the pipe size in Linux. E.g I would like that program can only write 20 bytes and then it waits until other end has read the data. I think you can not shrink named pipes to be so small. (Minimum size seems to be page file size (4096 bytes)?)

Thanks!

Comment: You need your own bi-directional protocol, not to depend on blocking on pipes.

Comment: I wonder why you need this? Isn't it possible to just block while the pipe is full?

Comment: Yes that is possible and I would like to have same functionality but for smaller amount of data than the pipe size. There can be multiple programs and I want that one program can write for example only 20 bytes to the pipe until it blocks.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY problem; blocking on writing is a very odd desire. Can you give more details on your actual task?

Comment: A simple approach would be to create a second pipe to acknowledge pieces of data received just as bmargulies suggested.

Comment: Okay ,I think I create another pipe to which I use to send ACKs like you suggested. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: can you use messages between processes?

Comment: It seems you want Unix domain sockets (specify message boundaries in application protocol) or Windows named pipes (they even have message mode) that allows bidirectional communications between unrelated processes.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have the reading process sending a signal to the writing process when it has read some data. You can do this using kill() to send SIGTERM to the writer, since SIGTERM can be catched and handled.

Comment: the OP requested read all data not some data. So you would need to read with timeout (and when timeout is reached the signal is sent)